# How to change Background color in a Video? SOFTWARES: Filmora or Adobe Premier pro

Tags: video

I have a little video animation. I want to change the backgroud color (Part of built-in Video) from black to white throughout the whole video without disturbing the main focused logo (RED logo).[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without the original assets, anything you do will be less than ideal.

In Premiere:

Because the background is black, you could change the Blend Mode in the Opacity settings to Screen.

[image: screen mode]